# Do Read receipts have an identifier for the "parent" sent email

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to send an email with read receipt in my application. When I receive the Read Confirmation email is there any unique identifier for the "parent" sent message so I can be sure they match and make a relationship in the database?

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

if (isNotify)
{
    //for delivery receipt
    message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
    //for read receipt
    message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", this.EmailInformation.From);
}
```

Comment: You could try explicitly setting a Message-Id header with a unique value perhaps using a GUID. This value __should__ then be reflected in the Original-Message-Id header of the read receipt email.

Comment: Remember, though, there's no guarantee that there's no guarantee that a read receipt will always be sent either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC 2298 (An Extensible Message Format for Message Disposition Notifications](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2298.txt):

> A message that contains a Disposition-Notification-To header SHOULD
>      also contain a Message-ID header as specified in RFC 822 [2].  This
>      will permit automatic correlation of MDNs with original messages by
>      user agents.

You could explicitly set a unique Message-ID header, this value **MUST** be returned in the Original-Message-ID of the read receipt email.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I used -> message.Headers.Add("Message-ID", messageIdString); and got it back in (ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message) -> message.Mail.InReplyTo